# Listagg, Excel Formula, concatenate, list, group, comma seperated

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, listagg

I am coming from Oracle SQL to excel. I wanted to know if there is an equivalent to LISTAGG in Excel. Please see the below sample data.
Also, there is table below for what I am looking for.
I want to concatenates values of the measure_column (AppID) for each GROUP (Person_ID) based on the order_by_clause (ascending).

Sample Data: See below

```
Table1  
Name    Person_ID
Name1   Person_ID1
Name2   Person_ID2
…   

Table2  
AppID   Person_ID
AppID1  Person_ID1
AppID1  Person_ID1
AppID2  Person_ID2
AppID3  Person_ID3
AppID4  Person_ID4
AppID5  Person_ID4
….
```

Here is what I want

```
Want
    Person_ID   App_IDs
    Person_ID4  AppID4, AppID5
    Person_ID1  AppID1, AppID1
```

Attempt Code

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(DNA_DCO!$B$2:$B$50000=B3,DNA_DCO!$A$2:$A$50000,""))
```

Comment: If that is the order of table 2, then I would use index() and match(), match the person-id then index the app-id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you. Enter with control + shift + enter.

`=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(A2=B7:B13,A7:A13,""))`

[image]